# Uploading to a remote server periodically?

Tags: file, ssh, ftp, remote-server

I have been working on an app that takes screen shots, kinda like http://puush.me/ however, I would like to be able to upload the screen shots to a remote server.

What protocols can I use to do so.

Needs to be cross platform and secure.

I know that SSH, SFTP and FTP are options, however, they all require logins that I dont want to provide to the end user. Nor do I want to sign a key for them as it would still allow their machines to remotely log in.

Comment: https should satisfy all the requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP Protocal allows for remote upload and I was able to give each uploader a unique Id